# Javascript: Weather API design question with hourly polling

Tags: javascript

I am doing practice interviews and specifically prepping for the Design portion.  One mentions:

****Design a weather widget that pull data from a service API which makes data available every hour. Avoid pulling the data from it all the time if there are no changes. Then what happens when you scale this to lots of users.****

My first thought would be obviously create a function that fetches the data from the GET endpoint and then parsing the JSON.
The part that would throw me off though is: "Avoid pulling the data from it all the time if there are no changes" .  How can I know there are no changes without first pulling the data?  My only thought would be to create a ignore flag:

1. Pull the data, mark the temperature as 55 Degrees.  Create a flag that ignores values of +/- 3 degrees from this temperature value.
2. Next hour, pull the data and see the temperature is 56 Degrees.  That is within the ignore flag range: (ex:  `if (Math.abs(temperature - nextTemp) > 3) {  ignoreFor5Hours = true; }` .  Then this will stop the hourly pulling for 5 hours, or however long someone set it to.
   Does this make sense or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: If the API only provides data hourly, then you know not to make calls more than once an hour. Cache the data retrieved with an hour expiry. Invalidating the cache fetches new data

Comment: thank you.  I assume the caching and invalidating the cache would best be done via a backend cron job, right?

Comment: You could do it that way or you could use a cache that's able to lock and fetch new data when it is invalidated (I'm sure there's a fancy name for that but it's not coming to me today). The lock is so only one thread performs the data retrieval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Assuming the data is not updated regularly***

It sounds quite confusing as there should be no method for the client side to actively know whether there is an update on the data before pulling it from the server.

One way I would suggest is to use two-ways communication, such as socket.io. That is, you establish a connection to the server, once there is an update, the server can initialize a call to your client app for fetching the data.

Another way is to use long pulling, or just like your interval fetching, to pull a hash from the server and check if the hash changed, which is also not ideal as you have to also load your server with a hanging request, but at least the data traffic will be smaller.

These methods are obviously not optimal, but if you must follow the guideline and it means what it means, those can be your options

***If the data is updated regularly***

Go with the caching option provided by Phil

Comment: thanks Kenny, I appreciate it!  I am just trying to expand the way I think about these questions and this helps, thanks :)

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I would do nothing special at all.

It should be up to the API to specify the appropriate `Cache-Control` headers.  The browser will handle the caching, so subsequent fetches will use the cache if applicable.

The API knows how fresh its data is, and knows when it expects to be updated.  It's also the case with weather that certain weather patterns change faster than others.  That's why it's up to the API to decide what to do.

Comment: thanks Brad.  Wouldn't the "ideal" scenario though be where the client didn't have to make a request to see if the cache was still applicable?

Comment: @ddjk The request won't actually hit the server if the local cache is sufficiently up to date.

Answer (score 0):

When you building an API, you should consider using **SSE** (server sent events) or **MQ** (message queue)

- SSE is a unidirectional and uses HTTP2 to stream the data/message
- MQ is a bi-directional and uses TCP/IP (probably not secure)

I would suggest to use SSE for this purpose, you would create an SSE endpoint on the server. This endpoint would simply stream the weather data to the client whenever it is updated. The client would then listen for updates to the SSE stream and update the weather widget accordingly.

This approach has the following advantages:

- It is more efficient than pulling the data from the API on a timer, because the client only receives updates when the data actually changes.
- It is more scalable than a messaging queue, because the server does not need to keep track of individual clients.
- It is simpler to implement than a messaging queue, because the client does not need to connect to a separate service.

However, this approach also has the following disadvantages:

- It is not as reliable as a messaging queue, because the client may miss updates if the connection is interrupted.
- It is not as flexible as a messaging queue, because the client cannot request specific updates.

Overall, this is a good approach for designing a simple and efficient weather widget. However, it is important to consider the disadvantages of SSE before using it in a production environment.

Here is a high-level overview of how to implement this approach:

- Create an SSE endpoint on the server that streams the weather data to the client.
- On the client, create a new EventSource object to listen for updates to the SSE stream.
- When the client receives an update, update the weather widget.

```js
const eventSource = new EventSource('/sse');

eventSource.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  // Update the weather widget with the new data.
});
```